# Unable to run the SDK manager

Tags: android, eclipse

I have download the bundle from
[Here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html),Now I run the eclipse then create a sample project in console the error is displayed.I have run the "**Android SDK Managaer**" the console it throw an error came.Can some one help me how to resolve issue.

**Error Log:**

```
[2014-07-07 16:53:41 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] '"E:\SOFTWA~1\ADT-BU~1\sdk\tools\lib\\find_java.exe" -s' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2014-07-07 16:53:41 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
[2014-07-07 16:53:41 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] '"E:\SOFTWA~1\ADT-BU~1\sdk\tools\lib\\find_java.exe" -s -w' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2014-07-07 16:53:41 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
[2014-07-07 16:53:41 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] '""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java.exe"" -jar lib\archquery.jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2014-07-07 16:53:41 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
[2014-07-07 16:53:41 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Invalid path
```

Unable to create a new emulator in the eclipse see the screen shot[image]

Comment: `Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Android 4.4W'` - Your minSdkVersion is too high for the emulators you have created. Lower it. Or create a new emulator which targets `'Android 4.4W'`

Comment: While run the project it asking to create new emulator.But I am unable to create a new emulator in eclipse.At the same time the error is came.

Comment: You have to use the AVD manager. Follow some tutorial.

Comment: Which version of SDK have you installed in you SDK manager 23.0 or 22.6

Comment: Hi @ user285oo6 I have used to SDK manajer 23.0 and java 1.6

Comment: Hi All I have edit the error log can some check and let me know please..